# Chrome Latest version (Version 47.0.2526.80 m) : navigator.webkitGetUserMedia returns a stream which doesnot have stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

I had implemented a piece of code to access camera on chrome browser and release it after use.
**Code:**

**Start Camera:**

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia($scope.options.videoObj, function (stream) {
    $scope.options.video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    $scope.options.video.play();
    $scope.options.localMediaStream = stream;                   
}, $scope.options.errBack);
```

**Stop Camera:**

```
    $scope.options.video.pause();               
    $scope.options.localMediaStream.stop();
```

But, after latest upgrade of **chrome browser**, i.e. **Version 47.0.2526.80** m, 
$scope.options.localMediaStream doesnot have "stop" function.

So, everything is breaking.
I need to release camera access so that another browser can access camera.
(Previously stop function was doing this work)

Please help me if someone has any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jai said in his answer, Chrome finally implemented the new `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` method.

[According to the specs](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/#dom-mediadevices-getusermedia), to stop the stream, you will now have to call the `stop()` method of every `mediaStreamTrack` Objects, not the one of the `MediaStream` one.

full code :

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var start = function(){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).then(function(mediaStream){
        window.stream = mediaStream;
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
        video.play();
    });
}
var stop = function(){
    if(stream.stop) {
        stream.stop(); // FF and other not yet updated browsers
    } else {
        // updated browsers
        var tracks = stream.getTracks();
        for(var i=0; i<tracks.length; i++) {
            tracks[i].stop();
        }
    }
    URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
}
```

or alternatively, to only release the camera, you can call
`stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop()`

Answer (score 1):

Seems chrome has removed it as this feature is deprecated.

> Later versions of Chrome support unprefixed `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`, that replaced this deprecated method.

[image]

**and the compatibility table for `.stop()` method:**

[image]

---

Instead you would use [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(mediaStream) { ... })
```

Comment: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is available only in FF.  Chrome browser doesn't have getUserMedia function on mediaDevices

Comment: @Jai : Still my question remains unanswered . How to stop/release camera access. i.e. i want any alternative to "stop" function

Answer (score 0):

$scope.options.localMediaStream=null;

Comment: It doesn't release camera. i.e. if you try to access camera through different browser, it throws camera inaccessible error.